# Doctrine insert/update/modify sub entities on @OneToMany

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a project based on Symfony 2.6. It has the following structure:

```
Customer->@OneToMany->Orders->@OneToMany->Domains->@OneToMany->SubDomains
```

same in reverse order:

```
SubDomains->@ManyToOne->Domains->@ManyToOne->Orders->@ManyToOne->Customer
```

Doctrine creates some additional pretty cool "magic" columns like `customer_id` (in domains), `order_id` (in domains) and `domain_id` (in `subdomains`).

It think it would be perfect, if all these `*_id` cols are filled with the IDs of the parent table. But in my case, that will not match all the time.
Only for tables `customer` and `order`, the `*_id` cols are filled properly.

My PHP code creates new Domain Entities. It also sets the ID, if the record exists in DB, and it adds all the `subdomains` as `ArrayCollection`.

Here is my `storeOrder()` method:

```php
protected function storeOrder(Order $order, array $domains) {
    if ($order->getDomains()->count() === 0) {
        // insert
        foreach ($domains as $domain) {
            $order->getDomains()->add($this->createDomainFromArray($domain));
        }
    } else {
        // remove/add
        $order->getDomains()->clear();
        foreach ($domains as $domain) {
            $order->getDomains()->add($this->createDomainFromArray($domain));
        }
    }
    //$updatedOrder = $this->entityManager->merge($order);
    // starts the commit process incl. transactions and prepared queries
    $this->entityManager->persist($order);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
    // clear all cached entities in em. That speeds up processing enormous
    $this->entityManager->clear();
    $this->amountOfDomains += count($domains);
}

/**
 * create a domain object from delivered data array
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return Domain
 */
protected function createDomainFromArray($data) {
    $domain = new Domain();
    $domain->setOrderNumber($this->orderNumber);
    $domain->fromArray(ArrayUtility::removeSubEntriesFromArray($data));
    $this->addIdToDomainIfFoundInDatabase($domain);
    $this->addSubDomainsToDomain($domain, $data['subdomain']);

    return $domain;
}

/**
 * To prevent duplicate domains in database we have to set the id,
 * if we have found such domain already in DB
 * @param Domain $domain
 */
protected function addIdToDomainIfFoundInDatabase(Domain $domain) {
    /** @var Domain|NULL $domainFromDatabase */
    $domainFromDatabase = $this->findDomainBySeid($domain->getSeid());
    if ($domainFromDatabase instanceof Domain) {
        $domain->setId($domainFromDatabase->getId());
    }
}

/**
 * find domain by seid
 *
 * @param int $seid
 * @return Domain|NULL
 */
protected function findDomainBySeid($seid) {
    // do not use empty, because findOneBy can also return NULL as result
    if (!isset($this->cache['domainFromDatabase']) || (is_object($this->cache['domainFromDatabase']) && $this->cache['domainFromDatabase']->getSeid() !== $seid)) {
        $this->cache['domainFromDatabase'] = $this->domainRepository->findOneBy(array(
            'seid' => $seid,
            'orderNumber' => $this->orderNumber
        ));
    }
    return $this->cache['domainFromDatabase'];
}

/**
 * add/override subdomains to domain object
 *
 * @param Domain $domain
 * @param array $subDomains These are the subDomains from request
 */
protected function addSubDomainsToDomain(Domain $domain, array $subDomains) {
    $first = TRUE;
    $this->amountOfSubDomains += count($subDomains);
    $domainFromDatabase = $this->findDomainBySeid($domain->getSeid());
    if ($domainFromDatabase instanceof Domain) {
        $subDomainsFromDatabase = $domainFromDatabase->getSubDomains();
    } else {
        $subDomainsFromDatabase = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    foreach ($subDomains as $subDomain) {
        // create new SubDomain
        $subDomainObject = new SubDomain();
        $subDomainObject->setOrderNumber($this->orderNumber);
        $subDomainObject->fromArray($subDomain);

        // add ID to subDomain, if we have one already in DB
        // It's not perfect, but as long as we can have fully equal records in subdomain table
        // I don't see any chance to change that
        if ($first) {
            $subDomainFromDatabase = $subDomainsFromDatabase->first();
            $first = FALSE;
        } else {
            $subDomainFromDatabase = $subDomainsFromDatabase->next();
        }
        if ($subDomainFromDatabase instanceof SubDomain) {
            $subDomainObject->setId($subDomainFromDatabase->getId());
        }

        // add Order to Customer
        $domain->addSubDomain($subDomainObject);
    }
}
```

Here are the annotation from order entity:

```php
/**
 * Order -> domains
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FQCN\Domain", mappedBy="order", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $domains;
```

Here are the annotations from subdomain entity:

```php
/**
 * relation from domain to order
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="FQCN\Order", inversedBy="domains")
 */
protected $order = NULL;

/**
 * domain -> subDomains
 *
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="FQCN\SubDomain", mappedBy="domain", cascade={"all"})
 */
protected $subDomains;
```

If I use only `flush()`, the `*_id` fields will not be filled. If I call `detach($order)`, the fields will be filled properly, but now I have a second (duplicate) of `$order` in my database. If I use `merge()` everything works on *INSERT*, but not if I want to update all my `ArrayCollections`.

What I'm doing wrong? How to *UPDATE* `ArrayCollections` the right way *without* removing and creating them again? How to get the `*_id` field filled?

Stefan

Comment: I don't really understand why you can't set up the id field for your entities so that doctrine doesn't magically add them? If you need to set them to specific values then you you don't have to auto-generate them? As long as they are unique it should be fine?

Comment: Welcome to SO, Stefan :) I [edited](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30944343/revisions) your post to make it a bit more readable. Hope you forgive me, please correct, if I removed important parts.

Comment: Thank you @StephenKing. Look much better. I miss my comment with merge() method. I have kept it here to show that I also have tried different things.

Comment: @redbirdo I don't want to set the id fields to specific values. My wish is, that doctrine fills them automatically for me with the right parent IDs. For now they are always NULL. If I call $this->entityManager->detach($order) the id fields will be filled correctly, but then I have a new duplicate in my Order table.

Comment: @froemken You've repeated what you said in the question which didn't make sense to me - it still doesn't. Please can you post your entity classes?

Comment: @froemken It would also be helpful to see the code for createDomainFromArray().

Comment: @redbirdo I have added some more code. Maybe it is a little bit more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. Here my solution:

I have added a new function to my domain model, to get the original subDomain object from database:

```
public function getSubDomain($seid) {
    foreach ($this->subDomains as $subDomain) {
        if ($subDomain->getSeid() === $seid) {
            return $subDomain;
        }
    }
}
```

In my DomainSynchronization-Object I decide between updated or new record:

```
$domainFromDatabase = $order->getDomain((int)$domain['seid']);
if ($domainFromDatabase instanceof Domain) {
    // update
    $this->updateDomainFromArray($domainFromDatabase, $domain);
} else {
    // insert
    $order->getDomains()->add($this->createDomainFromArray($domain, $order));
```

}

And, as @redbirdo already mentioned, I add the domain object to subDomains manually now:

```
protected function addSubDomainsToDomain(Domain $domain, array $subDomains) {
    $this->amountOfSubDomains += count($subDomains);
    foreach ($subDomains as $subDomain) {
        $subDomainObject = $domain->getSubDomain((int)$subDomain['seid']);
        if ($subDomainObject instanceof SubDomain) {
            // update
            $subDomainObject->fromArray($subDomain);
        } else {
            // insert
            $subDomainObject = new SubDomain();
            $subDomainObject->setDomain($domain);
            $subDomainObject->setOrderNumber($this->orderNumber);
            $subDomainObject->fromArray($subDomain);
            $domain->addSubDomain($subDomainObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I don't need a ->persist() or ->merge() anymore. It's enough to call:

```
$this->entityManager->flush();
```

Any I can see the parent UIDs now in subdomain table, too.

Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I notice that when you add a domain to an order you are calling:

```
$order->getDomains()->add($this->createDomainFromArray($domain));
```

Your order class should have these methods, then you can use addDomain():

```
public function addDomain(Domain $domain)
{
    $this->domains[] = $domain;
    return $this;
}

public function removeDomain(Domain $domain)
{
    $this->domains->removeElement($domain);
}
```

Adding those methods may be enough to fix your issue. However, I usually find it necessary to explicitly set both ends of a relationship, in this case between Order and Domain. I presume you aren't doing this since when you create a Domain you do not pass in the Order:

```
$order->getDomains()->add($this->createDomainFromArray($domain));
```

Try this instead:

```
$domain = $this->createDomainFromArray($domain);
$domain->setOrder($order);
$order->addDomain($domain);
```

You will need to do something similar with your SubDomains.

I can't see why you should need to use $em->detach() or $em->merge() although from the code in the question I don't know where the Order passed into storeOrder() is coming from.

Comment: The idea with $order->getDomains->add() I have from here [link]http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations

Comment: Shit: Hitting return equals SAVE here. And again: The idea with $order->getDomains->add() I have from here http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#establishing-associations But you're right, it seems that I have to set both side in bidirectional associations. Hm, so it is more MY job to fill these ID fields. Thank you. I will try.

Comment: Thank you. It works now. I have just answered my question